# Batch Rename Subdirectories in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, command-prompt, subdirectory

I have a directory with thousands of subdirectories that contain their own subdirectories that need to be renamed. I'm using a Windows 7 machine that I do not have Administrator rights for so I can't download a simple program to do this for me.

Right now I have a test directory `C:\test` with a few subdirectories that have subdirectories named `old` that I am trying to change to `new` using a batch file.

Just to be clear I want the following:

```
C:\test\1\old
C:\test\2\old
C:\test\3\old
```

to become

```
C:\test\1\new
C:\test\2\new
C:\test\3\new
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: have a look at robocopy and the for command (help for at the prompt will get you started)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with quickly. I ran a quick test locally and it seemed to do what you're asking for:

```
@echo off

FOR /D %%D IN ("C:\test\*") DO CALL :RENAME %%D

:RENAME
SET CRITERIA=\old
FOR /D %%R IN (%1%CRITERIA%) DO RENAME %%R "new"
```

Save that to a bat file and give it a shot. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: It worked for the test scenario I provided, but for the real folders I want renamed it isn't working. I'm not sure if it's because there are multiple subdirectories or if the special characters in the names of the subdirectories are affecting it.

Comment: So I've narrowed it down to the fact the subdirectories have parentheses. Is there a way around this?

Comment: That's interesting. The rename command should work for any valid directory name. Are the subdirectories only two levels deep? Meaning it only goes as deep as C:\test\1\old?

Comment: The actual directories are in this format: C:\test test\1111 (AAAA)\old

Comment: @innate: You probably needed to add quotation marks around `%%D` (the one after `:RENAME`), around `%1%CRITERIA%`, and around `%%R` (the one after `RENAME`). And it would also be a good idea to add `GOTO :EOF` after the first loop to jump over subroutine when finished. However, I don't think you need either a second loop or a subroutine here. Just replace `...DO CALL :RENAME %%D` with `...DO RENAME "%%D\old" new` and you should be done.

Comment: Thanks Andriy for cleaning that up. I kind of threw it together off what I could remember. :)

Answer (score 1):

Justin's answer was really helpful for my similar problem, though by default it only handled a  simpler pattern for \A\B\C where A is a base directory, B is some undetermined directory and C is the directory you seek.

I modifed his script to recurse the base directory A through any number of layers until it finds C.

Here's the script, written to expect command line paramers:

```
@echo off

set BASEDIR=%1
SET CRITERIA=\%2
SET REPLACENAME=%3

call :FindDirs %BASEDIR%

GOTO END

:FindDirs
FOR /D %%F IN ("%1\*") DO CALL :RENAME %%F
GOTO:EOF

:RENAME
REM echo DIR=%1
FOR /D %%R IN ("%1%CRITERIA%") DO (
    if EXIST %%R RENAME %%R "%REPLACENAME%"
)
call :FindDirs %1
GOTO:EOF
```

Comment: How about an example of how this works? I tried something like this: subfrn "_Release" "48x48" "40x40"  ... where subfrn is the bat file. I have a directory called _Release in the same directory as the bat file. I am trying to rename all subfolders of _Release with folder name 48x48 to 40x40

Comment: Actually this does work, although it returns an error when it's done. "The system cannot find the batch label specified"